# Did Orson Scott Card give Petra her own book?

Tags: enders-game

**Did the author of the Ender's Game book series give Petra her own book?**

Comment: Short answer. Nope.

Comment: OK thank you Richard, They should though

Comment: For me, the early ender's game books were of diminishing interest after each one.   He got really focused on silly ideas.

Comment: The speaker trilogy was "alright" really just because i needed to finish enders story, the shadow series was pretty meh.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on how you define "your own book".

Strictly speaking, the only two characters who had a whole book of their own were Ender, and Bean.

Most of the books however were ensemble books, and among them, Petra played one of the central roles. I would guess her biggest role was in the "Shadow of the giant", with screen time shared close to equally by Bean, Petra, Peter Wiggin, Alai, Han Tsu, Achilles and Virliomi; and Petra being arguably among the main 3 characters. She also has the closing action of the book's last chapter, reading "The Hegemon" at Peter's grave.

Answer (score 2):

### There was a planned book about Petra, but it got scrapped

In 1999, around the time of the release of *Ender's Shadow*, Orson Scott Card said in several interviews that there was going to be a book about Petra, after he finished the book he was then working on, *Shadow of the Hegemon*.

> Ender's Shadow is a parallel novel, beginning where Ender's Game begins and ending where it ends. There is a sequel planned, called Shadow of the Hegemon, in which we see Bean as the commander that Peter uses in the process of uniting all of humanity under one government. And I plan a book about Petra. Beyond that, I may write more or we may open the series to other writers.
> <sub>[CNN Interview, August 23 1999](http://www.cnn.com/books/dialogue/9908/orson.card/)</sub>

> At first, we wanted to bring other writers into the project. That still may happen with later books. But for now, these books are mine. There will be a sequel to ENDER'S SHADOW called SHADOW OF THE HEGEMON, and yet another book about Petra.
> <sub>[Barnes and Nobles Interview, August 31 1999](https://web.archive.org/web/19991128201359/http://timp.net/osclistgallery/transcript990831.htm/)</sub>

> If you thought Bean disapproved of Ender, wait till you read Petra's book ... and wait till you see what Bean thinks of Peter!
> <sub>[hatrack.com, October 5 1999](http://www.hatrack.com/research/questions/q0015.shtml)</sub>

However, in the event, there was no book published about Petra. She did have a significant role in *Shadow of the Hegemon*, as well as the two sequels that Card went on to write afterwards, but never her own stand-alone book.

This was because when he started writing them, Card found that the shadow series worked better as a single series about all of the Battle School kids, rather than individual books about each one.

> In the process of creating the whole shadow series, however, I found myself writing the stories of all the Battle School kids, including several that we never actually met in Ender’s Game. So instead of having a Bean novel, then a Petra novel, then a Dink novel, and so on, I wrote the five Shadow novels as an answer to the question, “What happened to all the Battle School kids after the war?” structured around Bean’s life.
> <sub>*Ender's World (2013)*</sub>